# Angular Router - two routes with same component

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have the following route to navigate to a data entry screen:

```
{
   path: 'model/:model',
   component: modelComponent,
}
```

That route can be shared between multiple items on the navigation system:

[image]

It works fine from the navigation standpoint, but as it is obvious, the data on both models is the same. I am trying to figure out a way of cloning modelComponent for each screen. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what your issue is.

Comment: What is your angular version?

Comment: Angular version 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try To use the Path with the resolve
First Create a resolve like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ModelResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private dataService: YourDataService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    const model = route.paramMap.get('model');
    return this.dataService.getModelData(model);
  }
}
```

You can create a dynamic component that wraps your modelComponent. This dynamic component will receive the resolved data and pass it to modelComponent.

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-model-component',
  template: '<modelComponent [data]="resolvedData"></modelComponent>',
})
export class DynamicModelComponent {
  @Input() resolvedData: any;
}
```

And Finaly add it in your routher path

```js
{
  path: 'model/:model',
  resolve: {
    resolvedData: ModelResolver,
  },
  component: DynamicModelComponent,
}
```

Modify your modelComponent to accept data as an input:
In your modelComponent, make sure it can accept data as an input so that the resolved data can be passed to it.

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'modelComponent',
  template: '<div>{{ data }}</div>',
})
export class ModelComponent {
  @Input() data: any;
}
```

Comment: By using this you can map the same data in different Modules

Comment: The route already has a resolver. But I think I see your point. The solution is in the data management, not in the making multiple clones of the same object. Although, the later is more elegant.